# Append specific character to a new div with jquery on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a RPG game and I have 4 characters for the player to choose from. So when a user choose character #1, that character will move to a new div and the rest to a different div. I tried appendTo but it will move all of the character since they are under the same class. Any suggestion?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".character_all").on("click", function() {
    var characterSelected = $(".character_all");
    characterSelected.appendTo("#chosen_character");
 });
});
```

Comment: You'll need to assign a specific id to each character and select them based on their unique id. Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you Jake!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need. You are just need to use the right selector for the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".select").on("click", function() {
 $(".select").appendTo("#enemy");
 $(this).appendTo("#appendTo");
 });
});
```

```css
.div{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:yellow;
}
label{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}
#appendTo{
  background:lightblue;
   height:50px;
  width:50px;
  
}
#enemy{
   background:red;
   height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
 <label class="select">
  A
</label>
<label class="select">
  B
</label>
<label class="select">
  C
</label>
</div>
<div id="appendTo">
</div>
<div id="enemy">
  
</div>
```

Let me know if it solves your problem and if you face any issues.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey Manish, it work. Thank you so much. So now, would I do the same if I want to move the rest of the character to the enemy div?

Comment: ok so you want the selected one to move to a different div and rest to move to a different div right. Have updated the answer have a look. And mark it as answer if it solves your issue :)

Comment: perfect, if I want to append to another div for the third time, is it better to use a for loop with an if and else statement? Also, how do I mark as answer? sorry I'm still new with stackoverflow. Thank your for your help

Comment: what is better depends completely on your requirement. So using a for loop with if is fine as far as your requirement is fulfilled and there are no other issue coming up because of that. And u r welcome  Always happy to Help :)